# Magnetic Effect In Slider

Tags: c#, silverlight, slider, effects

look i have Slider in Silverlight having maximum value of 1 starting from minimum value of 0,

i want the slider to have some magnetic effect, like if i drop slider thumb near 0 it must return to 0.

for example , if i drop the thumb between (0 - 0.50) say 0.40 the very thumb must move to 0, and if thumb drop at value more than 0.50 it must move to 1.

```
<Slider Height="50" x:Name="slider" Width="160"  Maximum="1" SmallChange="1" LargeChange="1" Minimum="0" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about the `ValueChanged`-Event?

Build in something like this:

```
slider.Value = slider.Value <= 0.5 ? 0 : 1;
```

Comment: This worked for me, @Faizan can you post your updated XAML and cs code?

Comment: @Karl It Working Great on "Mouse Left Button Up" event, where as on ValueChanged Event it not so Flexible it just accessing defined values i.e. 0 and 1 not between them.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class SnappySlider : Slider
{
    public SnappySlider()
    {
        this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(Slider);
    }

    protected override void OnValueChanged(double oldValue, double newValue)
    {
        base.OnValueChanged(oldValue, newValue);
        Value = Value < 0.5 ? 0 : 1;
    }
}
```