# Set step of Slider to non-integer value in Silverlight

Tags: wpf, silverlight, slider

I do have a Slider with set minimun and maximum, but the intermediate value is not integer (ex. 4.51294141512 etc). How can set the step of the slider slider to non-integer values?
May by step is 1, 5, but not 9.4148257822

Answer (score 0):

This is not available in the standard Slider.

You could subclass the Slider as mentioned here: [Magnetic Effect In Slider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8576429/magnetic-effect-in-slider)

Answer (score 0):

Create an event: `nameslider_valueChanged` and round the value.

**Example**

`SAnios` is name of slider control

```
Private Sub sAnios_ValueChanged(sender As Object, 
                                e As RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs(Of Double))
    If Not IsNothing(sAnios) Then          
        sAnios.Value = FormatNumber(sAnios.Value, 0)   
    End If 
End Sub
```

The `If Not IsNothing` is to prevent an error when loading the app.